# How to coerce a type in SML (like casting)

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm creating a structure of Rationals (int * int) and one of my functions is:

```
fun diff ((n, d), (n', d')) = 
  let 
    val (top, bot) = sum ((n, d), (~n', d'))
  in 
    (top / gcd(top, bot), bot / gcd(top, bot))
  end
```

`gcd` gives me the greatest common denominator, so I don't end up with 2/8, but rather 1/4 as it should be. `gcd` uses `mod` to find the gcd, so it returns an `int`. But I can't get the expression with division to be typed as an int. When I tried adding `: int * int` to the end of the `diff` declaration, it gives me a type error that the expressions `real * real` and `int * int` don't match.

How can I force integer division, or cast the expression to an integer? If both are possible, which one is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah you are using the wrong operator. `/` is the floating-point division operator. `div` (as mentioned by D.Shawley) is the integer division operator. `div` is the right thing to use in this case, because you are dividing two integers and want to get an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Does SML have a `div` operator by any chance? It's been years since I've played with ML but it seems like a pretty standard way to force integer division.